# Google Cloud Platform - Project vanished

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, instance

I have a project that seems to have completely vanished from my Google Cloud Platform.

I only had a simple instance and Wordpress site on there - the domain is still pointing a google ip address (beginning 35.178), and appears to be still connecting to *something*, however the site isn't up as it can't conenct to a database.

Logging into my google cloud platform, my project doesn't exist any more. I haven't deleted it and it's not in the "marked for deletion" list - it's not something I have a lot of interaction with daily at all.

I've also checked all of my other cloud computing logins to see if I was mistaken and the project/instance exists somewhere else, but nothing, it's as if it has completely vanished.

Has anybody else ever experienced this? Is this a solvable problem?

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of situation where is unlikely that any other StackExchange user will be able to provide you help, I would advise you to open a support ticket directly with the [Google Cloud Billing team](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) Then you can provide them with some data such as your project Id and ask them why you don’t have visibility of it.